# Dictionary unpacking in python

Tags: python, dictionary

For a list, I can split it with one compact line of code:

```py
i_ate = ['apple', 'beetroot', 'cinnamon', 'donut']

# Elaborate
first = i_ate[0]
rest = [item for j, item in enumerate(i_ate) if j != 0]

# Shortcut
first, *rest = i_ate

# Result in both cases:
first # 'apple'
rest # ['beetroot', 'cinnamon', 'donut']
```

**Does someting similar exist for dictionaries?**

```py
i_ate = {'apple': 2, 'beetroot': 0, 'cinnamon': 3, 'donut': 8}

# Elaborate
apples = i_ate['apple']
rest = {k: v for k, v in i_ate.items() if k != 'apple'}

# Shortcut??
# -- Your line of code here --

# Result in both cases:
apples # 2
rest # {'beetroot': 0, 'cinnamon': 3, 'donut': 8}
```

Comment: props for the well described question with examples and attempted code

Comment: I'm not quite sure, where you see potential or even necessity for improvement in the dictionary example. Your list "simplification" looks just better due to its start with an overcomplicated enumerate-expression, which can be dropped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about unpacking the dict as items? This will work on any python version that supports ordered dicts

```
>>> _, *rest = i_ate.items()
>>> dict(rest)
{'beetroot': 0, 'cinnamon': 3, 'donut': 8}
```

As slothrop in the comments suggested, if `first_value` is also needed, the first item can further be unpacked:

```
>>> (_, first_val), *rest = i_ate.items()
>>> first_val
2
```

[`.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict%20values#dict.items) converts the dictionary into a sequence of tuples

Alternatively, just delete the entry you don't want in-place using `del i_ate['apple']` or `i_ate.pop('apple')`.

Comment: or to extract the first value as well, as in OP's suggested result: `(_, first_val), *rest_items = i_ate.items()`. Then `first_val` is 2.

Comment: @slothrop good callout thanks! added to the answer with credit